# mail.google.com popup

Tags: google-chrome, email, mail

I have Kubuntu 21.10 and recently reinstalled Plasma 5.22.5,and now receive an annoying popup Authentication Dialog "you need to supply a username and password to access this site mail.google.com".

I google mail on Chrome browser and have logged out and in again, no change. I do not think I have evolution, thunderbird, kmail or any other mail client on my system. Kwallet is not enabled.

How can I turn off this popup, or find out what process is generating the popup?

Thx, Gus

Answer (score 1):

I believe the offending package is plasma-gmailfeed - uninstall it and logout of desktop. Then log back in.